# gRPC response type issue

Tags: c#, api, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a gRPC service `DeviceCommWeb`, which has the following rpc in the .proto file:

```cs
// NOTE: This is part of the .proto file

service DeviceCommWeb {
  rpc GetConnectedDevices(GetConnectedDevicesRequest) returns (stream GetConnectedDevicesResponse);
}
```

The `GetConnectedDevicesRequest` message:

```cs
// NOTE: This is part of the .proto file

message GetConnectedMessageRequest {
  enum DeviceType {
    USB = 0;
    HDMI = 1;
    DisplayPort = 2;
  }

  DeviceType deviceType = 1;
  string pdiUid = 2;
}
```

The `GetConnectedDevicesResponse` message:

```cs
// NOTE: This is part of the .proto file

message GetConnectedDevicesResponse {
  repeated DeviceComm devices = 1;
}
```

In the service I have the implementation of `GetConnectedDevices`:

```cs
public override async Task GetConnectedDevices(GetConnectedDevicesRequest, IServerStreamWriter<GetConnectedDevicesResponse> repsonseStream, ServerCallContext context)
{
  await responseStream.WriteAsync(ListConnectedDevices((DeviceType)request.DeviceType, Guid.Parse(request.uid)));
}
```

The `ListConnectedDevices` method:

```cs
private GetConnectedDevicesResponse ListConnectedDevices(DeviceType deviceType, Guid uid)
{
  var connectedDevices = DeviceCommMoq.ConnectedDevices() // This is just a Moq. Returns a List<DeviceComm> of DeviceComm objects.

  var result = new GetCOnnectedDevicesResponse();

  foreach (DeviceComm device in connectedDevices)
  {
    // This is where I'm confused. How do I build the GetConnectedDevicesResponse?
  }
}
```

The goal is the get the list of connected devices in `DeviceCommMoq.ConnectedDevices()`, and return them as a (or a stream of) `GetConnectedDevicesResponse`. I'm not sure how to go about this, and everything I try gives me the error:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'DeviceComm' to 'GetConnectedDevicesResponse'`

What am I doing wrong? I feel like there is a better way to achieve the end goal here.

Comment: Where you say `Should`, it most likely returns another type.

Comment: I edited the original post, it definitely returns a list of `DeviceComm` objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `WriteAsync()` means you have to read data specific.

First, call `using var response = yourGrpcClient.GetConnectedDevices()` to get `ResponseStream`. Then read data:

```
await foreach (var data in response.ResponseStream.ReadAllAsync())
{
   //Do Stuff
}
```

Also, if you're using streams, `WriteAsync()` every element in foreach loop.

**EDITED**

There many errors in your solution. Lets start with `.proto` file. Response contains multiple `DeviceComm` elements. It's wrong, because you are using stream as response, it's means streaming elements of `GetConnectedDevicesResponse` type, so you should redefiend it. Replace `repeated DeviceComm devices = 1;` with DeviceComm properies.

After this change `GetConnectedDevices` method like this:

```
public override async Task GetConnectedDevices(GetConnectedDevicesRequest,
  IServerStreamWriter<GetConnectedDevicesResponse> repsonseStream,
  ServerCallContext context)
{
  var connectedDevices = deDeviceCommMoq.ConnectedDevices();
  foreach(var device in connectedDevices)
  {
    await responseStream.WriteAsync(new GetConnectedDevicesResponse() { *Initialize properties from device object* });
  }
}
```

And after this, you can use client example.

Comment: I tried following this, but I'm not quite sure where/how to implement it. This seems like it would happen in the service, and not the client?

Comment: @LunaMarie Edit my answer

Comment: I've implemented the service bit in the `GetConnectedDevices` method, but I get an `Object reference not set to an instance of object` on this line: `await responseStream.WriteAsync(new GetConnectedDevicesResponse() { // Stuff }`

Also, I'm still unclear on how to implement the client side of things. I can't seem to access the ResponseStream.

Thank you for all of your help thus far @lobstar